# calculating mean and SD of a column

Tags: awk

I have following lines in my file,

```
echo "Start 2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF 2831 3230"
echo "dimensions 9248 49"
echo "New Cell"
grep "3065,46" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.09 17.2412 78.2198 210 1.83619 6 6
grep "3066,46" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 42.31 17.2616 78.252 210 9.86289
grep "3066,47" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 30.94 17.3031 78.2253 210 2.13253
grep "3067,46" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.67 17.2821 78.2842 210 2.93917
echo "New Cell"
grep "3067,17" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.32 16.1507 78.9842 210 2.19602 7 7
grep "3067,18" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.69 16.1895 78.961 210 6.56008
grep "3067,19" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.49 16.2281 78.9379 210 5.46735
grep "3068,16" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 27.31 16.1322 79.0394 210 2.16296
grep "3068,17" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 42.16 16.1711 79.0163 200 4.16615
grep "3068,18" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 48.1 16.2099 78.9931 210 24.642
grep "3068,19" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 49.15 16.2485 78.97 210 29.2187
grep "3069,17" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.98 16.1914 79.0484 210 3.68008
grep "3069,18" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.04 16.2302 79.0252 210 4.7225
grep "3069,19" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 34.08 16.2688 79.0021 210 6.04774
echo "New Cell"
grep "3069,09" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.43 15.8757 79.2349 210 3.33878 8 8
grep "3070,09" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 22.61 15.896 79.2669 292 1.05899
echo "New Cell"
grep "3071,15" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 37.63 16.154 79.159 210 1.20265 9 9
grep "3071,16" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 38.84 16.1932 79.1357 210 7.35424
grep "3072,14" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.34 16.1352 79.2142 210 0.616139
grep "3072,15" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 43.13 16.1743 79.1911 210 7.59137
grep "3072,16" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20080401.59125.7.HDF.txt.text = 40.94 16.2135 79.1678 210 14.7196
```

There are multiple seq of echo "New Cell", Start, dimensions statements.

I have to take the average of 10th column which are 1.823, 9.36 etc. 
I tried

```
awk '{ ave+= $10; n=n+1} END { if (n > 0) print ave / n; }'
```

which sums the 10th column of the entire file and gives me ONE value.

But I want the average of in between the echo "New Cell" lines.

```
The expected out put should be.
```

echo "New Cell"
Count =4, average = 3.8 (example, there are 4 lines between 2 echo "new Cell" lines and average of 10th column of these 4 lines is to be taken)

```
echo "New Cell"
```

Count = 10, average = 6 (example,there are 10 lines between 2 echo "new Cell" lines and average of 10th column of these 10 lines is to be taken)

and so on. 
How to add the if statement in awk.

Comment: I tried to format you text a bit, but the shell commands makes little sense as you have text mixed in with them. Could you please sort it out so that it's readable?

Comment: `(1.83619 + 9.86289 + 2.13253 + 2.93917)/ 4` gives `4.19`, but not `3.8`

Comment: Wait, that thing with shell code and text is your actual input file?

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/echo "New Cell"/{    # on encountering line with `echo "New Cell"` 
         if (sum) {        # if calculated sum exists
             c = NR - n;   # get number of processed records
             printf "%s Count = %d, average = %.2f\n", $0, c, sum/c;
             sum = 0
         } 
         n = NR + 1        # get the initial record position/number
     }
     n{ sum += $9 }' file
```

The output:

```
echo "New Cell" Count = 4, average = 4.19
echo "New Cell" Count = 10, average = 8.89
echo "New Cell" Count = 2, average = 2.20
```

Comment: Assuming the filename in the input data has no spaces.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it does not make much sense to rely on field numbers if filepath could have space(s).

Comment: Then maybe delete up to the first `=` and use that as data?

Comment: @Kusalananda, then maybe the OP should elaborate if that moment is really required?

Comment: @geet, see my explanation